# ASP.NET MVC / C# 2010 Best Practises?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I'm starting to find myself becoming quite uneasy about the cleanliness of my code..

To give you some background i learned C# from a .Net 2.0 book written a long time ago, after starting to use the ASP.NET MVC framework for some small apps i'm starting to realise that i'm not being as efficient as i could be..

What are your like "top ten best practises" for a .Net 2.0 dev trying to get into the year 2010?

Stuff like dependency injection (Which i have pretty much no knowlege of) etc..

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

One common phrase to keep in mind when doing MVC development is to keep your models heavy (or fat) and your controllers light (or thin).  It's very easy to throw a lot of logic into the controllers and they end up being very procedural in nature.  But, ideally, the business logic should be encapsulated in the models and the controllers are really just event handlers (action methods) which call the domain logic in the models to perform a task.

Answer (score 2):

You can read this great book for beginers in ASP.NET MVC IoC and TDD
[Steven Sanders](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865)

Answer (score 1):

With the improvements of the language, from .net 2 through to 4 you can clean up your code simply by using auto properties.

So instead of using the follow

`private string myVariable;`

```
public string MyVariable
{
 get
 {
   return myVariable;
 }
 set
 {
   myVariable = value;
 }
}
```

You can replace with:

```
public string MyVariable {get;set;}
```

Another options is strongly typed views when displaying model data instead of `ViewData["Something"];` Although this could be addressed in the case of the recently release RC2 of v3 `ViewBag.Something` instead.

Hope this helps